# My GeoLocation Does not Seem to use Cache

Tags: google-chrome-extension, geolocation

I see alot of people complaining about how GeoLocation uses cache.... But my problem is that mine does not seem to use cache. My Weather API needs coordinates in order to be called, and the function to call the API is triggered once my GeoLocation gets its coordinates. The results appear on an HTML page, and if I open up a bunch quickly its almost instant, but after maybe 10 seconds it stops using the cache. I set maximumAge to 5400000, 1.5 hours, and that does not seem to work. Please let me know if you have any ideas! Thanks so much in advance.

Here is my GeoLocation Code if you are interested:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction, geo_options);

function successFunction(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log("lat:" + lat + " long:" + long);
    callWeather(); // function that contains API call and Jquery to append
                  //the HTML file
}

function errorFunction(position) {
  console.log('Error with Position!');
}

var geo_options = {
  maximumAge: 54000000, //wait an hour and a half before updating position, 
                        //allows for quicker calls to weather api?
  timeout: 10000 // wait 10 seconds before giving up on position
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to find out where the lag really was-

```
console.log("called position:"+d.getSeconds()+":"+ d.getMilliseconds());
```

and found out it was my weather api that was holding back the HTML display:

> from the log (it is in minutes/seconds/milliseconds):

```
content.js:232 called position: 48:36:915
content.js:329 called weather: 48:39:150
```

I'm using DarkSky for my weather API. I wonder how I can speed that up...